# how to add an integer value to a date and calculate the end date in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, console-application

I am building a c # console application.

Assume  user inputs as

- no of effort for task in hours = 48
- no of working hours per day = 9
- start date = 26/02/2021

How can I  display the end date of the task after excluding the weekends and public holidays.

I have already implemented the user inputs by considering all possible validations.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //effort hours
    Console.Write("Enter No of hours: ");
    int hours;
    if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out hours))
    {
        if (hours <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hours of effort cannot be a negative value or 0");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The no of hours entered is: " + hours);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have entered an incorrect value.");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();

    //working hours per day
    Console.Write("Enter No of working hours per day: ");
    int WorkingHours;
    if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out WorkingHours))
    {
        if (WorkingHours <= 0 || WorkingHours > 9)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Maximum working hours per day is 9 hours and no of hours entered cannot be 0 or negative");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The no of working hours entered is: " + WorkingHours);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have entered an incorrect value.");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();

    //Enter start date
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the start date date (e.g. dd/mm/yyyy): ");
    DateTime startDate;
    {
        while (!DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out startDate))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered an incorrect value.");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the start date date (e.g. dd/mm/yyyy): ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The startdate is: " + startDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you define public holidays? Different countries have different public holidays.

Comment: You'd definitely need a calendar containing what in the domain is considered "weekend", "public holiday" and/or even "company holidays" (I happen to be an employee of a company, where this is a thing, actually. 'Bridge-Days' like a friday between a WE and a holiday on a thursday are mandatory 'no work'-days.) SO, having that, you'd calculate the date regardless of the calendar, then look if any of these non-workdays fall into that range, then add the number of these days, then look if more of non-workdays fall into the added range, rinse, repeat, until this not the case any more.

Comment: Unrelated to the logic: You don't loop or bail on **in**valid input. That doesn't make sense. If I enter "jello!" for "work hours / day", it doesn't make sense to go on to ask what's the start date.

Comment: Each country has a different date format. `DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out startDate)` does *NOT* use `dd/mm/yyyy`, it uses the format used in the user's locale. In the US it will be `mm/dd/yyyy`. In Russia `dd.mm.yyyy`

Comment: To actually count working days you *do* need a Calendar. Working days and hours differ even among different sectors in the same country. Even among companies.

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for pointing out the mistake in the logic of invalid input.I will correct it.

Comment: @Flidor Thanks a lot for your explanation. I will try to implement accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this problem without looping is like this:

```
static void Main ( string[] args ) {

    BeginRoutine:
        //effort hours
        Console.Write( "Enter No of hours: " );
        int hours;
        if ( Int32.TryParse( Console.ReadLine(), out hours ) ) {
            if ( hours <= 0 ) {
                Console.WriteLine( "Hours of effort cannot be a negative value or 0" );
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine( "The no of hours entered is: " + hours );
            }
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine( "You have entered an incorrect value." );
        }
        //Console.ReadLine();

        //working hours per day
        Console.Write( "Enter No of working hours per day: " );
        int WorkingHours;
        if ( Int32.TryParse( Console.ReadLine(), out WorkingHours ) ) {
            if ( WorkingHours <= 0 || WorkingHours > 9 ) {
                Console.WriteLine( "Maximum working hours per day is 9 hours and no of hours entered cannot be 0 or negative" );
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine( "The no of working hours entered is: " + WorkingHours );
            }
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine( "You have entered an incorrect value." );
        }
        //Console.ReadLine();
    
    GetStartDate:
        //Enter start date
        Console.WriteLine( "Enter the start date date (e.g. dd/mm/yyyy): " );

        DateTime startDate;
        while ( !DateTime.TryParse( Console.ReadLine(), out startDate ) ) {
            Console.WriteLine( "You have entered an incorrect value." );
            Console.WriteLine( "Enter the start date date (e.g. dd/mm/yyyy): " );
        }

        // Make sure the start date isn't a Saturday or Sunday!
        if ( startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ) {
            Console.WriteLine( "Cannot start work on {0} because it is a {1}",
                startDate.ToString( "MM/dd/yyyy" ), startDate.DayOfWeek );

            goto GetStartDate;
        }
        Console.WriteLine( "The startdate is: " + startDate );
        
        // Determine number of work days:
        double workDays = hours / WorkingHours;
        Console.WriteLine( "\nTask will take {0} work days", workDays.ToString("0.00") );

        // Determine total weeks and days:
        double totalWeeks = workDays / 5D;
        double totalDays = ( totalWeeks * 7D );

        // Print statistics to Console for user
        Console.WriteLine( "Task will take {0} weeks and {1} total calender days ...", 
            totalWeeks.ToString( "0.00" ), totalDays.ToString( "0.00" ) );

        // Calculate ending date and display it:
        DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(totalDays);
        Console.WriteLine( "The ending date will be {0}", endDate.ToString( "MM/dd/yyyy" ) );
        
        // Prompt user to restart:
        Console.WriteLine( "\n\nProgram complete ... press Y to restart or any other key to continue.\n" );
        if ( Console.ReadKey( true ).Key == ConsoleKey.Y ) goto BeginRoutine;
    }
```

I haven't exhaustively tested this routine against all possible scenarios, and it's surely not the "best" way to do this (for instance, it doesn't account for holidays like Christmas and is not localized for regions and cultures) but it seems to solve your simple problem in a quick and performant manner. Oddly enough, I was just writing some pretty interesting DateTime code for my strategy game prototype where I use the game loop to drive a DateTime forward and create an in-game time system.

EDIT: Note that I pretty much left your original code intact and just added beneath it ... an easy way to solve for holidays would be to create a list of dates containing holidays, see if any fall in between start date and end date (perhaps with a custom query) and just add a day for each one that is.

Comment: Glad it helped. You can expand upon that to do more sophisticated things like skipping over holidays. Simply make a holiday list and see which ones are in between start and end date. Add one day to totalDays for each one that is, then simply call DateTime.AddDays and you've got accurate prediction with holidays (which can be based on any country or culture's holidays). The beauty of this approach is that there's no slow looping or confusing logic. We solve the problem by simple arithmetic.

Comment: Yes, of course. I used simple goto statements to keep the code short and simple. But you can replace that with things like local functions inside of Main, or create some static methods inside of the Program class that implement parts of the routine. Then Main will simply call a method like Begin() inside of a loop or recursion as long as Console.ReadKey(true).Key equals the Y key ... very simple restructuring.

Comment: I modified the code by including more possible scenarios and now I get an error in the output(endDate) when the workdays exceeds 10.But I get the correct output for instances where workdays is less than or equal to 10.I couldnt figure out my mistake in it..I posted the question with the modified code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68956766/how-can-i-solve-the-error-in-the-calculation-logic-for-the-below-scenario-and-ho.Can you please look into it and help me  if possible.Thankyou.

Comment: You actually messed it up and didn't add anything but errors, but I respected your effort and posted an alternative solution using static methods without goto statements. I'm leaving some of the work up to you, though.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you would need to provide Holiday List which would be different across the world. Additionally, the defined "workdays"/"weekends" could also vary depending on the region you are developing the application for. For example, some of the middle-east countries have weekends on Thursday/Friday.

Assuming you have regular Saturday/Sunday weekends, you could modify the DateTime Extension provided by [FluentDateTime](https://github.com/FluentDateTime/FluentDateTime/blob/master/src/FluentDateTime/DateTime/DateTimeExtensions.cs) as following to include a collection of Holidays

```
public static class Extentions
{

    public static DateTime AddBusinessDays(this DateTime current, int days,IEnumerable<DateTime> holidayList)
    {
        var sign = Math.Sign(days);
        var unsignedDays = Math.Abs(days);
        var holidayCollection = new HashSet<DateTime>(holidayList);
        for (var i = 0; i < unsignedDays; i++)
        {
            do
            {
                current = current.AddDays(sign);
            } while (current.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday 
                   || current.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday 
                   || holidayCollection.Contains(current));
        }
        return current;
    }
}
```

You could now use the method as

```
startDate.AddBusinessDays(totalHours/perDayHours,holidayList)
```

If as mentioned earlier, you would need to consider a different weekend, you need to make appropriate changes in the code above.

PS: Above code assumes you are interested only in "EndDate" and not to accurate hour.