# How can I solve the error in the calculation logic for the below scenario and how to remove goto statement in the below implementation in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, console-application, goto, parseint

I am building a c # console application.

**User inputs considered,**

- number of effort for task in hours
- number of working hours per day
- start date

And display the end date of the task **by excluding weekends(saturday,sunday).** and  number of working days to complete

**Validations that I have considered,**

- number of effort for task in hours must be always greater than 0 and user can only input an integer
- maximum no of working hours per day is 9 hrs and user can only input an integer
- start date cannot be saturday or sunday
- end date displayed should also be a weekday.

**My Implementation**

```
    public static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        BeginRoutine:
            ////effort hours
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Total Time for the Task in Hours : ");

            var correctValueForHours = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int totalHoursOfTask);



            if (correctValueForHours)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Total Time for the Task is : " + totalHoursOfTask);

                if (totalHoursOfTask > 0)
                {
                GetWorkingHours:
                    ////working hours per day
                    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter No of working hours per day: ");

                    var correctValueForWorkingHours = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int workingHoursPerDay);

                    if (correctValueForWorkingHours)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Total Work Hours Per Day is : " + workingHoursPerDay);

                        if (workingHoursPerDay > 0 && workingHoursPerDay <= 9)
                        {


                        GetStartDate:
                            //Enter start date
                            Console.Write("\nEnter the start date of the task (e.g.mm / dd / yyyy) : ");

                            var correctValueForStartDate = DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out DateTime startDate);

                            if (correctValueForStartDate)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Start Date is : " + startDate);

                                if (startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday || startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday || startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday || startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday || startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
                                {

                                    double workDays = (double)totalHoursOfTask / (double)workingHoursPerDay;
                                    int RoundedworkDays = (int)Math.Ceiling(workDays);
                                    Console.WriteLine("\nTask will take {0} working days", RoundedworkDays);
                                    DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(RoundedworkDays + 1);

                                    if (endDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                                    {
                                        DateTime newEndDate = endDate.AddDays(2);
                                        Console.WriteLine("The ending date will be {0}", newEndDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
                                    }
                                    if (endDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                                    {
                                        DateTime newEndDate = endDate.AddDays(1);
                                        Console.WriteLine("The ending date will be {0}", newEndDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
                                    }
                                    Console.WriteLine("The ending date will be {0}", endDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
                                }
                                else if (startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Cannot start work on {0} because it is a {1}", startDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), startDate.DayOfWeek);

                                    goto GetStartDate;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("You have entered an incorrect value for start date. Please enter a correct value");
                                goto GetStartDate;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (workingHoursPerDay > 9)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("You have entered " + workingHoursPerDay + " But the maximum working total Hours Of Task per day is 9 totalHoursOfTask. Please press space key to start from the beginning");
                            goto GetWorkingHours;
                        }
                        else if (workingHoursPerDay <= 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("You have entered " + workingHoursPerDay + " But the minimum working total Hours Of Task per day is 1 hour and no of totalHoursOfTask entered cannot be 0 or negative");
                            goto GetWorkingHours;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have entered an incorrect value for working hours. Please enter a correct value");
                        goto GetWorkingHours;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have entered " + totalHoursOfTask + " But total Hours Of Task cannot be 0 or negative");
                    goto BeginRoutine;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have entered invalid value for total hours of task. Please enter a correct value");
                goto BeginRoutine;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nProgram complete ... press Y to restart or any other key to exit.\n");
            if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Y) goto BeginRoutine;
        }
    }
```

The problem I am having is when the number of working days is less than or equal to 10 I get the correct outputs as expected.But the output gets wrong when the number of working days exceed 10.

one of the sample data and outputs have been included below,

- number of effort for task in hours = 130
- number of working hours per day = 04
- start date = 08/02/2021

The Output got is as follows which is wrong.

```
Task will take 33 working days
The ending date will be 09/06/2021
The ending date will be 09/05/2021
```

How can I correct the issue?

And also I want to **remove**  **goto statement** and use an alternative way to accomplish my task. (I would like to know how to use seperate methods and do the implemetation,So that whenever a new input parameter is introduced, it will be easy to amend the code.I referred some articles but I find it difficult to apply it in my scenario).Can Someone please help me to do it?
I am new to c#.

Any help is appreciated.

Thankyou.

Comment: Has your C#-education-provider taught you what a method is yet?

Comment: I hope they release a C# version at some point that bans stuff like `goto` labels and `#region`s.

Comment: So whats the alternative that I can  used to accomplish my task and how to do?@CamiloTerevinto

Answer (score 1):

Your code full of goto and nested ifs its so hard to follow, debug, and mantain

Below a version using methods and no goto; it's far from perfect, but that I think you will find much easier to work with.

I actually spent much more time in understanding what your code does than in writing this code: I've never felt the need to use `goto`, maybe it can be useful in some very specific scenario (don't know which), in "normal" code it's just a way to obfuscate it

```
public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int totalHoursOfTask;
        bool keepOn = true;
        do
        {
            keepOn = false;
            if (!TryGetHoursOfTask(out totalHoursOfTask))
                continue; // no valid input, let's start from the beginning

            int workingHoursPerDay = GetWorkingHoursPerDay();

            DateTime startDate;
            bool startDateOK;
            do
            {
                startDateOK = TryGetStartDate(out startDate);
            } while (!startDateOK);

            Console.WriteLine("Start Date is : " + startDate);

            if (startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot start work on {0} because it is a {1}", startDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), startDate.DayOfWeek);
                continue; // no valid stard date, let's start from the beginning
            }

            int workingHoursPerDay = GetWorkingHoursPerDay();
            DateTime endDate = ComputeEndDate(startDate, totalHoursOfTask, workingHoursPerDay);

            Console.WriteLine("The ending date will be {0}", endDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));

            keepOn = AskUserToConinue();
        } while (keepOn);

    }

    private static bool TryGetHoursOfTask(out int totalHoursOfTask)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Total Time for the Task in Hours : ");

        if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out totalHoursOfTask))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered invalid value for total hours of task. Please enter a correct value");
            return false;
        }

        // NOTE, you should check for our >=0

        return true;
    }

    private static bool TryGetStartDate(out DateTime startDate)
    {
        Console.Write("\nEnter the start date of the task (e.g.mm / dd / yyyy) : ");

        if (!DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out startDate))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered an incorrect value for start date. Please enter a correct value");
            return false;
        }

        if (startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot start work on {0} because it is a {1}", startDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), startDate.DayOfWeek);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static int GetWorkingHoursPerDay()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter No of working hours per day: ");
        bool ok;
        int workingHoursPerDay = 0;

        do
        {
            ok = false;
            if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out workingHoursPerDay))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have entered an incorrect value for working hours. Please enter a correct value");
                continue;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Total Work Hours Per Day is : " + workingHoursPerDay);
            if (workingHoursPerDay > 9)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have entered " + workingHoursPerDay + " But the maximum working total Hours Of Task per day is 9 totalHoursOfTask. Please press space key to start from the beginning");
                continue;
            }
            if (workingHoursPerDay <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have entered " + workingHoursPerDay + " But the minimum working total Hours Of Task per day is 1 hour and no of totalHoursOfTask entered cannot be 0 or negative");
                continue;
            }
            ok = true;
        } while (!ok);

        return workingHoursPerDay;
    }

    private static DateTime ComputeEndDate(DateTime startDate, int totalHoursOfTask, int workingHoursPerDay)
    {
        double workDays = (double)totalHoursOfTask / (double)workingHoursPerDay;
        int RoundedworkDays = (int)Math.Ceiling(workDays);
        Console.WriteLine("\nTask will take {0} working days", RoundedworkDays); // not really nice, writing on a console whilecomputing end date... could be improved

        DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(RoundedworkDays + 1);

        switch (endDate.DayOfWeek)
        {
            case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                endDate = endDate.AddDays(2);
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                endDate = endDate.AddDays(1);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        // NOTE: you are not considering weekends occurring within (e.g.) a 30 days job.

        return endDate;
    }

    private static bool AskUserToConinue()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nProgram complete ... press Y to restart or any other key to exit.\n");
        return Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have changed something. I ran the exact same code I gave you last night without any changes, and entered the same values:

130 hours of work
4 hours of work per day
Start date: 8/2/21

---

Output:

***Task will take 32.00 work days***

***Task will take 6.40 weeks and 44.80 total calender days ...***

***The ending date will be 09/15/2021***

---

I hand-counted them on the calender and confirmed that 9/15/21 is the correct date ... this was the same, unmodified code I posted in your question last night and it computes the correct results. So, I'm guessing you changed something or you made a mistake in your console input.

Here it is again, just tested it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main ( string[] args ) {

    BeginRoutine:
        //effort hours
        Console.Write( "Enter No of hours: " );
        int hours;
        if ( Int32.TryParse( Console.ReadLine(), out hours ) ) {
            if ( hours <= 0 ) {
                Console.WriteLine( "Hours of effort cannot be a negative value or 0" );
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine( "The no of hours entered is: " + hours );
            }
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine( "You have entered an incorrect value." );
        }
        //Console.ReadLine();

        //working hours per day
        Console.Write( "Enter No of working hours per day: " );
        int WorkingHours;
        if ( Int32.TryParse( Console.ReadLine(), out WorkingHours ) ) {
            if ( WorkingHours <= 0 || WorkingHours > 9 ) {
                Console.WriteLine( "Maximum working hours per day is 9 hours and no of hours entered cannot be 0 or negative" );
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine( "The no of working hours entered is: " + WorkingHours );
            }
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine( "You have entered an incorrect value." );
        }
        //Console.ReadLine();
    
    GetStartDate:
        //Enter start date
        Console.WriteLine( "Enter the start date date (e.g. dd/mm/yyyy): " );

        DateTime startDate;
        while ( !DateTime.TryParse( Console.ReadLine(), out startDate ) ) {
            Console.WriteLine( "You have entered an incorrect value." );
            Console.WriteLine( "Enter the start date date (e.g. dd/mm/yyyy): " );
        }

        // Make sure the start date isn't a Saturday or Sunday!
        if ( startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ) {
            Console.WriteLine( "Cannot start work on {0} because it is a {1}",
                startDate.ToString( "MM/dd/yyyy" ), startDate.DayOfWeek );

            goto GetStartDate;
        }
        Console.WriteLine( "The startdate is: " + startDate );
        
        // Determine number of work days:
        double workDays = hours / WorkingHours;
        Console.WriteLine( "\nTask will take {0} work days", workDays.ToString("0.00") );

        // Determine total weeks and days:
        double totalWeeks = workDays / 5D;
        double totalDays = ( totalWeeks * 7D );

        // Print statistics to Console for user
        Console.WriteLine( "Task will take {0} weeks and {1} total calender days ...", 
            totalWeeks.ToString( "0.00" ), totalDays.ToString( "0.00" ) );

        // Calculate ending date and display it:
        DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(totalDays);
        Console.WriteLine( "The ending date will be {0}", endDate.ToString( "MM/dd/yyyy" ) );
        
        // Prompt user to restart:
        Console.WriteLine( "\n\nProgram complete ... press Y to restart or any other key to continue.\n" );
        if ( Console.ReadKey( true ).Key == ConsoleKey.Y ) goto BeginRoutine;
    }
}
```

Changing it to use methods or local functions without goto statements is trivial. I did it that way just to make it very short and demonstrate the solution by pure arithmetic without any distractions. If you don't understand how to do it I can show you. People will tell you goto statements are "evil", but they're not. They're not good practice in large projects or real production code, but they're perfectly fine in a simple console app when you want to keep an entire routine inside of Main ...

EDIT:

Ok, I see now that you rewrote your program. But you've got a lot of ugly stuff in there. For example, you check to make sure the starting date isn't on a weekend like this:

```
if ( startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday || startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday || startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday || startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday || startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday )
```

No ... just do this:

```
if ( startDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && startDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday )
```

... then you know you have a valid startDate value and you don't need to do any more if statements to check on it. In your implementation, you did that big long check to see if it's Monday || Tuesday || Wednesday (and so on) and then check it *again* to see if it's a Saturday or Sunday, which is verbose and unnecessary.

Also, you do not need to Round off the work days to 33 ... DateTime.AddDays already computes the correct date for you in my example above, and you can even make it compute the correct time of day as well by setting the time of startDate to the time a work day begins at. Again, you're over-complicating something simple.

After that, I have no idea what you're trying to do. You didn't compute the extra days for weekends skipped, you just made some ugly if/else statements that simply add one day to endDate which is computed incorrectly to begin with. Basically, you messed everything up when you already had a working solution.

EDIT (again): Original version actually worked correctly somehow and I would have thought it'd be wrong. Somehow it's correct. I'm looking over it now. Will show a more "proper C#" implementation in a moment without any goto statements and using separate methods.

Comment: considering that OP was not able to handle the code **_he_** wrote to get the desired output, I'd say that even in this "simple console app" `goto` made code hard enough.

Comment: Hi,the problem iam having here is imagine user entered -5 as hours of work,then the error message should be displayed and must allow the user to enter hours of work again right.Here it doesnt loop.Instead it askes for the next user input of working hours per day even in an invalid scenario.So I modified the code by including a loop so that user can enter the 2nd field(working hours per day) only after he enters a valid input for the 1st input(hours of work).

Comment: And also in the input scenario of no of hours = 20 ,working hours per day = 8 and start date 08/02/2021...The output getting is as 6 working days.Then there is a balance of 2 hours.So In my case as I consider only the no of days to complete the task,shouldn't it be 7 working days? Hoping So I have implemented roundoff function.Now after considering all these scenarios I modified the code as above.Then I get an error in the calculation.

Comment: @rissa, i really suggest you to invest some time in understanding how structuring your code with method can simplify your life, instead of keep fighting with a 100 line single method full of nested ifs and goto. which, as you have already realized, is so hard to fix

Comment: Thankyou so much for your clarifications and pointing out the mistakes..I would be really grateful if you can show me how to use methods or local functions instead of go to.I am new to c#

Comment: Well, hold on ... I rewrote it without gotos and I think I found a bug in the logic. Checking it now. I'll show him the more "proper C#" way of doing this.

Comment: I figured out what it is. If the work ends at the end of a working day, it gives you the next day as the ending date even though you technically finished it at the end of the previous day. The program is still "correct" in its calculations, it's just not informing you that the work was finished at the end of the previous day. And if that happens to be a Friday, it spills over to the coming Monday.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's a more "proper" implementation without goto statements and using static methods.

One thing to keep in mind, however, is that these calculations aren't 100% perfect. After studying it, I noticed that if the work is completed at the end of a work day (like the 8th hour of an 8hr work day), it gives you the next day as the day it will be complete. If that day happens to be a Friday, it will give you the following Monday.

Since I basically did all the heavy work for you, I will leave the challenge of solving that minor issue up to you. This, however, should be enough for you to learn from and figure out what you're doing:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void BeginRoutine ( ) {

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine( "Compute Working Days:\n" );

        (int, int) hoursResult = GetHours();
        int hours = hoursResult.Item1, WorkingHours = hoursResult.Item2;

        DateTime? nullableResult;
        while ( ( nullableResult = GetStartDate() ) == null ) ;
        DateTime startDate = ( (DateTime)nullableResult );
        Console.WriteLine( "The startdate is: " + startDate );

        // Determine number of work days:
        //double workDays = hours / WorkingHours;
        double workDays = ( hours / WorkingHours );
        Console.WriteLine( "\nTask will take {0} work days", workDays.ToString( "0.00" ) );

        // Determine total weeks and days:
        double workWeeks, totalDays;

        workWeeks = workDays / 5D;
        totalDays = workWeeks * 7D;

        // Print statistics to Console for user
        Console.WriteLine( "Task will take {0} weeks and {1} total calender days ...",
            workWeeks.ToString( "0.00" ), totalDays.ToString( "0.00" ) );

        // Calculate ending date and display it:
        DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(totalDays);
        Console.WriteLine( "The ending date will be {0}", endDate.ToString( "MM/dd/yyyy" ) );
    }

    static (int, int) GetHours ( ) {
        // Get total number of work hours:
        Console.Write( "Enter No of hours: " );
        int hours;
        if ( Int32.TryParse( Console.ReadLine(), out hours ) ) {
            if ( hours <= 0 ) {
                Console.WriteLine( "Hours of effort cannot be a negative value or 0" );
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine( "The no of hours entered is: " + hours );
            }
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine( "You have entered an incorrect value." );
        }

        // Get number of work hours per day:
        Console.Write( "Enter No of working hours per day: " );
        int WorkingHours;
        if ( Int32.TryParse( Console.ReadLine(), out WorkingHours ) ) {
            if ( WorkingHours <= 0 || WorkingHours > 9 ) {
                Console.WriteLine( "Maximum working hours per day is 9 hours and no of hours entered cannot be 0 or negative" );
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine( "The no of working hours entered is: " + WorkingHours );
            }
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine( "You have entered an incorrect value." );
        }

        return (hours, WorkingHours);
    }

    static DateTime? GetStartDate ( ) {

        //Enter start date
        Console.WriteLine( "Enter the start date date (e.g. dd/mm/yyyy): " );

        DateTime startDate;
        while ( !DateTime.TryParse( Console.ReadLine(), out startDate ) ) {
            Console.WriteLine( "You have entered an incorrect value." );
            Console.WriteLine( "Enter the start date date (e.g. dd/mm/yyyy): " );
        }

        // Make sure the start date isn't a Saturday or Sunday!
        if ( startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ) {
            Console.WriteLine( "Cannot start work on {0} because it is a {1}",
                startDate.ToString( "MM/dd/yyyy" ), startDate.DayOfWeek );

            return null;
        }

        return startDate;
    }

    static void Main ( string[] args ) {

        do {
            BeginRoutine();
            Console.WriteLine( "Press Y to restart, any other key to end ..." );

        } while ( Console.ReadKey( true ).Key == ConsoleKey.Y );
    }
}
```